# signing SOAP XML using node-js using private key

Tags: web-services, ws-security, netweaver, node-soap

Am trying to sign the XML using my private key, and using SOAPUI
it gives the proper success response.

to generate the request am using below code

```
var Authorization = 'Basic ' + new Buffer((sapConfig.sap.username + ':' + sapConfig.sap.password) || '').toString('base64');
        soap.createClient(__dirname + '/wsdl/SI_CARWORKZ_Customer_Sen_Sync.wsdl', wsdlOptions, function (err, client) {
            client.setSecurity(new soap.WSSecurityCert(privateKey, publicKey, password, 'utf8'));   
            //client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(privateKey, publicKey, ca));    
            client.SI_CARWORKZ_Customer_Sen_Sync(details, sslOptions, function(err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
            console.log('%j', result);
            if(_.has(result, "ResponseData") && !_.isEmpty(result.ResponseData.Item)){
                var status = _.pluck(result.ResponseData.Item, "Status");
                if(status.indexOf('E') != -1){ 
                    return callback({status: "error", data: result});   
                }else{
                    // insert the user in mongodb
                    sapLogs.insertCustomers(details.HEADER, function(result){
                        console.log("customer added");                  
                        return callback({status: "success", data: details});    
                    })
                }
            }else{
                return callback({status: "error", data: [], message: "something went wrong." })
            }
            }, {"Authorization": Authorization});   
        });
```

But when am sending the signed xml data using the script it shows me error

> Error while validating the digital signature. The error was java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to invoke the method com.sap.security.core.ws.wss.tokens.securitytoken.BinarySecurityToken.getSecurityToken()

Is there any issue with my public key or private key?

I have exported them from **jks** file which is used in SOAPUI.